# How Getting Unknown variable number of parameters url or unlimited url variable in retrofit

Tags: android, url, parameters, generator, retrofit2

I want getting unknown variable number of parameters URL in **Retrofit** .number of parameter unlimited in URL .

How get and define this in Retrofit and Android. How generate URL unlimited in retrofit and android.

**For Example:**

http://api.aa.net/aaa/bbb/cc/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7,....

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Try this http://square.github.io/retrofit/